# Uploading File with Express (node.js)

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express

I'm trying to make a extremely simple file uploading server with node.js and express 4.0.0. According to http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads I think I should be getting "req.files", but it doesn't exist (is undefined).

```
var express = require('express')
var fs = require('fs')
var app = express()

app.get('/', sendForm)
app.post('/upload', uploadFile)
app.listen(8000)

function sendForm(req, res)
{
    // a form with a <input type="file">
    res.send('<!doctype html><html><head></head><body><form action=\"/upload\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"><input type=\"file\" name=\"displayImage\"><button type=\"submit\">submit</button></form></body></html>')
}

function uploadFile(req, res)
{
    console.log(req.files) // prints undefined
    res.redirect('back')
}
```

Some websites suggest adding "app.use(bodyParser)" and such called by "app.configure()". As far as I can tell, "app.configure" has been removed from express 4.0.0.

Why doesn't req.files exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find [Formidabble](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable) easy to work with, this is how you would use it:

```
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs         = require('fs');

module.exports.upload = function (req, res, next) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        if ('file' in files) {
            var file = files['file'];

            // Do something with file

            module.exports._deleteFiles(files);
            res.send(200);
        } else {
            module.exports._deleteFiles(files);
            res.send(400);
        }
    });
};

module.exports._deleteFiles = function (files) {
    // Delete temporary files
    for (var f in files) {
        fs.unlink(files[f].path);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently most middleware was [taken out of Express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#overview).

You need to include middleware to populate `req.files` -- something like [connect-multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/connect-multiparty).

Include `var multiparty = require('connect-multiparty');` with your module imports, and after you have an `app`, add the middleware with `app.use(multiparty());`.

Make sure to clean up temp files, and potentially only pass multiparty as middleware for routes that explicitly will take uploads.